# "Error: expected expression before" the first line of my function

Tags: c, expression

I am getting this error when I am compiling..."stock.c:103: error: expected expression before ‘stock_t’"...is there some thing that I am doing wrong?

```
stock_t * createStockHolding(
     char * name, float closing, float opening, int shares, 
     float (* getPrice) (void * S),
     float (* getTotalDollarAmount)(void * S),
     float (* getPercentChange)(void * S),
     char * (* toString)( void * S)) {

        stock_t * newStock = (stock_t*)malloc(sizeOf(stock_t));
        newStock->stockSymbol = name;
        newStock->closingSharePrice = closing;
        newStock->openingSharePrice = opening;
        newStock->numberOfShares = shares;
        newStock->getPrice = getPrice;
        newStock->getTotalDollarAmount = getTotalDollarAmount;
        newStock->getPercentChange = getPercentChange;
        newStock->toString = toString;
        return newStock;
 }
```

Comment: And you include the header file where `stock_t` is declared?

Comment: Having a function with more than 5 parameters usually means there is a design problem.

Comment: Could you paste some lines above this code, the error might be in one of those.

Comment: How `stock_t` is defined?

Answer (score 5):

It is the capital O of `sizeOf`. You must use `sizeof` (small `o`).

Comment: @ouah Is it a new *warning* message? The *error* message is still there? What is the compiler output?

Comment: @Dave right, I was focused on the *implicit declaration* diagnostic.

Comment: @ouah `malloc()` is defined in the `stdlib.h` header file. You need to include it. The *implicit declaration* warning message will disappear.

Comment: @Bechir you will also get an *implicit declaration* diagnostic because of 'sizeOf' typo if you compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`.

Comment: @Bechir I think you've got your people muddled; ouah isn't the OP.